# What is the name of this Song?

Tags: song-poetry, satmar

I've got an idea that this question is going to get closed, but on [Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5494/can-i-ask-a-question-on-recognising-a-song) I did not get any answers on if it is allowed to post it here, so here I go.

In a online shiur by Rav  [דוד צבי רוזנבוים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9D), [a song is played](https://youtu.be/8_DPBR4eDWc?t=2104). Does anyone know the song? It sounds like starting with מה רבו, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The words are from [ברכת אהבה רבה](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94): "אהבה רבה אהבתנו ה' אלוקינו, חמלה גדולה ויתרה חמלת עלינו" in an Eastern-Southern Yiddish accent. Here's the recording: [ניגון אהבה רבה - סאטמאר בני ברק](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNvj7gYzA20)

Comment: Thanks, found it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A huge thanks to @Deuteronomy for pointing in the right direction. I found the right song. It is called [ניגון אהבה רבה - סאטמאר בני ברק](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNvj7gYzA20) - Nigun Ahavah Rabbah, by Satmar Bnei Brak. From the choir: Satmar'e Kafelye - Bnei Brak and solist Rabbi Shlomo Razman HI Yungel.

Here are the lyrics:

**ווערטער:**

> אַהֲבָה רַבָּה אֲהַבְתָּנוּ, יְיָ אֱלהֵינוּ. חֶמְלָה גְּדוֹלָה
> וִיתֵרָה חָמַלְתָּ עָלֵינוּ:
>
> אָבִינוּ מַלְכֵּנוּ בַּעֲבוּר שמך הגדול ובעבור אֲבוֹתֵינוּ שֶׁבָּטְחוּ
> בְךָ. וַתְּלַמְּדֵם חֻקֵּי חַיִּים לַעֲשׂות רְצונְךָ בְּלֵבָב שָׁלֵם
> כֵּן תְּחָנֵּנוּ וּתְלַמְּדֵנוּ :
>
> אָבִינוּ הָאָב הָרַחֲמָן. הַמְרַחֵם. רַחֵם עָלֵינוּ. וְתֵן בְּלִבֵּנוּ
> בִינָה לְהָבִין וּלְהַשְׂכִּיל. לִשְׁמֹעַ. לִלְמד וּלְלַמֵּד. לִשְׁמר
> וְלַעֲשׂוֹת וּלְקַיֵּם אֶת כָּל דִּבְרֵי תַלְמוּד תּורָתֶךָ
> בְּאַהֲבָה:
>
> וְהָאֵר עֵינֵינוּ בְּתורָתֶךָ. וְדַבֵּק לִבֵּנוּ בְּמִצְוֹתֶיךָ.
> וְיַחֵד לְבָבֵנוּ לְאַהֲבָה וּלְיִרְאָה אֶת שְׁמֶךָ. לְמַעַן לֹא
> נֵבושׁ וְלֹא נִכָּלֵם וְלֹא נִכָּשֵׁל לְעולָם וָעֶד: כִּי בְשֵׁם
> קָדְשְׁךָ הַגָּדוֹל וְהַנּוֹרָא בָּטָחְנוּ. נָגִילָה וְנִשְׂמְחָה
> בִּישׁוּעָתֶךָ:
>
> ורחמיך הרבים אל יעזבונו נצח סלה ועד. מהר והבא עלינו ברכה ושלום מהרה
> מארבע כנפות כל הארץ, ושבור עולנו מעל צווארינו, ותוליכנו מהרה קוממיות
> לארצנו.
>
> כִּי אֵל פּועֵל יְשׁוּעוֹת אָתָּה. וּבָנוּ בָחַרְתָּ מִכָּל עַם
> וְלָשׁוֹן. וְקֵרַבְתָּנוּ לְשִׁמְךָ הַגָּדול
>
> סֶלָה בֶּאֱמֶת, באהבה, להודות לך וליחדך באהבה, וליראה את שמך.